# vim -- 'go to previous buffer' broken

Tags: vim

In my `vim` and `gvim` the memory for `previous buffer` is not functioning properly. It did work well before but I cannot say when it started to misbehave.

If I have opened more than 2 files as buffers in one vim session, the command `:b#` always gets me back to the buffer which I have opened first (instead of getting me back to the previous buffer).

What might be the reason for this?

Interesting enough, if I delete a buffer, then`:b#` restores it.

I am on `Ubuntu 14.04`, my vim version is `7.4.52` and I have installed the [`bufexplorer` plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42).

Comment: Remove that plugin: if the problem goes away, file a bug report on the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It is indeed the `bufexplorer` plugin. More precisely, the `<leader>be` command seems to resort the history.

Comment: And I have filed a bug report on this topic: https://github.com/jlanzarotta/bufexplorer/issues/18

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the bufexplorer issue tracker. To point you in the right direction; read `:h edit-intro`, specifically `:h keepalt`. Then take a look at the [bufexplorer source code](https://github.com/jlanzarotta/bufexplorer/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=keepalt).